# Accept Function for C Sockets Not Working in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, sockets

I am trying to open a socket that sends and receives data from another socket. This socket acts like the server socket, where it listens on a port and then opens a socket, or accepts a computer's request to connect. The error I get when I try to run the `accept()` function is `No matching function call for accept!` I no similair questions have been asked, but they have been asked about their own methods and functions. This is not a function I wrote, and it should work. I plan to make a gui interface for this so I have it running in an objective c app in Xcode. Also, while doing research on c sockets, I saw that a website used the accept function just like I am using it and it worked. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int sock, newsock, port, clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    port = 460;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(sock, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

}
```

Comment: Did you include <sys/socket.h> ? I have a projecting doing this and it works.

Comment: why do you have this tagged as c?  If you want to tag it as C, you should provide working C code and errors from a C compiler

Comment: Sorry for tagging it for c I just thought that it would be appropriate because this is a c socket, not objective c.

Comment: @radarhead I did include that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, "*No matching function call for [...]*" is a C++ error, neither C nor Obj-C code produces this error. What is your file named like? Being an Obj-C file, it should have an extension "*.m*". If it has an extension "*.mm*", it is an Objective-C++ file, that means a file that mixes C++ and Obj-C and here things get more complicated. If you didn't intend to create an Obj-C++ file, yet the file is named "*.mm*", make sure to change the extension. Further you can select the type of a file in Xcode, overriding the auto selection of Xcode (that depends on its extension), make sure you have not overridden it to Obj-C++.

Comment: Thanks I suppose that was the problem because I did have it as a .mm file. Before you answered I just copied and pasted the code into a new document and that worked, but thanks for the information. It will be useful to me.